# Cannot query with IN() on indexed column

Tags: cassandra, scylla

I have simple table. Here is how it looks:

```
create table trip_stops
(
    cid      uuid,
    stop_id  uuid,
    rate     float,
    date     date,
    primary key ((cid), stop_id)
);
CREATE INDEX ON trip_stops ((cid), date); // local secondary index
```

Then I am doing query as follows:

```
select sum(rate) from trip_stops where
      cid = aa9e4310-e439-423c-86e5-53ddd7c74609
            and date in ('2019-01-01', '2019-01-02');
```

It fails and asks for `allow filtering`. Shouldn't the result of this query must be in a single partition and no need for internode data exchange?
Thanks in advance.

I run the query and it fails, expect it to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a ScyllaDB bug, tracked (for the similar case of ordinary, non-local, secondary index) in https://github.com/scylladb/scylladb/issues/13533:

An "IN" together with a secondary index is not supported; In Cassandra it gives an error ("IN predicates on non-primary-key columns (x) is not yet supported"), in Scylla instead it is *wrongly* done using slow filtering (with either an error or a warning that ALLOW FILTERING is needed).

Unfortunately, as a workaround today, you will need to split the IN request into multiple requests.

Answer (score 2):

The definition you posted for creating an index is invalid:

```
CREATE INDEX ON trip_stops ((cid), date)
```

The `CREATE INDEX` command only allows a single column to be indexed. The correct syntax is:

```
CREATE INDEX ON table_name (column_name)
```

In any case, your query is failing because native secondary indexes do not support the `IN()` operator. Only the equality (`=`) operator is supported for "regular" columns (as opposed to collection columns).

Since you are restricting the query to a single partition, it is not necessary to index the date column. You can simply run your query with `ALLOW FILTERING`:

```
SELECT rate FROM trip_stops
  WHERE cid = aa9e4310-e439-423c-86e5-53ddd7c74609
  AND trip_date IN ('2019-01-01', '2019-01-02')
  ALLOW FILTERING
```

The only recommended usage of `ALLOW FILTERING` is when the query is limited to a single partition. Filtering on a non-primary column within a partition works by design since the coordinator does not need to scan the whole table (expensive and inefficient) -- it just needs to scan the rows of a partition. Cheers!

Comment: Erick, actually ScyllaDB has an extension called **local secondary index** (see https://opensource.docs.scylladb.com/stable/using-scylla/local-secondary-indexes.html) which allows exactly this - a separate index per partition, where to look up you need to specify both the partition key and the value of the indexed column.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. Is it necessary though given that the query is restricted to a partition? Cheers!

Comment: That's the essence of the "local secondary index" - each query needs to be restricted to the partition, the index is "local" in that partition.

Comment: Note that exactly the same question can be asked about good-old-ordinary (not "local") secondary index, and the same bug exists there too. Cassandra gives you an error if you try to use "IN" in a query with a secondary index while in Scylla the bug is more "subtle" - it tells you to use ALLOW FILTERING (and when you do, the implementation is very slow and doesn't use the secondary index).

Comment: Oh, and you're right - in this user's specific use case, because the indexed column is a clustering key, it doesn't need to be indexed at all :-) If you just drop the index completely, the query should just work.